# swift CollectionView inside TableView Cell

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview

Why am I scroll first cell then third cell also scrolling?

[Screen Record](https://media.giphy.com/media/7XoD900wUYRGnkKTo8/giphy.gif)

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: This is happening because of cell reuse. You'll need to have some persistent data for every separate cell that will be triggered on cellForRow.

Comment: Explain your problem, show some of your code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of cell reuse, so basically the cell that you scroll goes off screen and will be reused when another cell down is needed.

In your `UITableViewCell` subclass you can implement `prepareForReuse` method, this is called when cell is ready to be reused and you can set contentOffset to 0 there, something like:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```